# (OpenGL 3.1 - 4.2) (GLSL) Efficient Uniform Variables?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm planning on rendering multiple instances of a single model by modifying various uniform variables (such as location, rotation, et al.).

Is there a better way then modifying the uniform variables for every instance I want to render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instanced rendering you can use the [ARB_instanced_arrays](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/instanced_arrays.txt) extension. With this extension you can define your not-so-uniform variables in a standard vertex array, and with the [glVertexAttribDivisor](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribDivisor) function you can fine tune when the not-so-uniform variable change.

Comment: As a side note, instanced arrays have been made core in OpenGL 3.3. And even before that you could still use instanced rendering (which is core since GL 3.0 or 3.1, I think). You just have to store the per-instance parameters in a uniform array/buffer and access them using the special shader variable `gl_InstanceID`.